# Cant open up oracle web console after install db 11gr2 and show weird symbols?

Tags: database, oracle, web

i just finished installing oracle database 11gR2. after successful install, i will usually want to open up web console at `http://localhost:1158/em`..
however if i open up the page i get a weird symbol on the top left. i also cant login to the db using any db management software.(im using toad)

Could anyone help me as to what i should do to fix this?and i would also like to what is the cause of this?

This is the error i got:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/207/errorph.png/

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that dbconsole still runs on port 1158? Log in to your server as oracle owner and try

```
emctl status dbconsole
```

In my case it was set on port 5500 after install with default settings.